# getting error only with vercel deployment when displaying props (works locally)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I am building a headless wordpress CMS(and using next.js template) .

I was able to successfully deploy to the vercel servers, I then started to add some content, in this case the Wordpress title field.. and this works great on my local server and display the title properly with no errors.. but when I update my git it kills the vercel deployment and I get this error.. I also get this error if I try to use content or dangerouslySetHTML

to clarify, if I remove this, it deploys fine
{ page.title }

```
Unhandled error during request: TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
--
17:01:15.529 | at Page (/vercel/workpath0/.next/serverless/pages/[slug].js:1634:412)
```

this is my page code [slug].js

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Link from 'next/link'
import Container from '../components/container'
import MoreStories from '../components/more-stories'
import HeroPost from '../components/hero-post'
import Intro from '../components/intro'
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import { getAllPagesWithSlug, getAllPagesBySlug } from '../lib/api'
import { CMS_NAME } from '../lib/constants'
import Header from '../components/header'


export default function Page( {page} ) {

  return (
    <>
      <Layout>
        <Head>
          <title></title>
        </Head>
       <Header />
        <Container>
        
        { page.title }
          
        </Container>
      </Layout>
    </>
  )
}


export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    
  const data = await getAllPagesBySlug(params.slug)
  console.log(data)
  
  
  return {
    props: {
      page: data.page,
  
    },
  }
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const allPages = await getAllPagesWithSlug()

  return {
     
     //paths:  [ { params: { slug: '${node.uri}' } }  ],
    paths: allPages.edges.map(({ node }) => `/${node.slug}`) || [],
    fallback: true,
  }
}
```

this is my query  lib/api

```
const API_URL = process.env.WORDPRESS_API_URL

async function fetchAPI(query, { variables } = {}) {
  const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }

  if (process.env.WORDPRESS_AUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN) {
    headers[
      'Authorization'
    ] = `Bearer ${process.env.WORDPRESS_AUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN}`
  }

  const res = await fetch(API_URL, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query,
      variables,
    }),
  })

  const json = await res.json()
  if (json.errors) {
    console.error(json.errors)
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch API')
  }
  return json.data
}

export async function getAllPagesBySlug($id) {
  const data = await fetchAPI(`
    {
     
        page(id: "${$id}", idType: URI) {
            uri
            slug
            content
            title
            featuredImage {
              node {
                sourceUrl
              }
            }
          }
    }
  `)
  return data
}
```

Comment: What did you get on the `console.log` on the `getStaticProps`?

Comment: Hello,  
page: {
    uri: '/contact-artist/',
    slug: 'contact-artist',
    content: '<p>For inquiries regarding the purchase of paintings or commissions</p>\n' +
      '<p>Call: <a href="tel:416.450.5439">416.450.5439</a></p>\n' +
      '<p>Email: <a href="mailto:sales@justinblayney.com">sales@justinblayney.com</a></p>\n',
    title: 'Contact',
    featuredImage: null
  }

Comment: some pages have no content or title, but that shouldn't matter.. it works 100% error free on http://localhost:3000/.. error is only on vercel

Comment: I would code more defensively and add a check for `data.page` before returning in `getStaticProps`: `if (!data.page) { return { notFound: true } }`. This would cover any issues with non-existing data from the CMS.

Comment: Thanks juliomalves 

I added that, still fails on vercel server, exact same error.

Unhandled error during request: TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined